# why are my mat-form-fields affecting each other?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have two separate mat-form-fields from the angular material library. When I use one everything is working as intended in the first picture below.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
<mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
<mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="range" [rangePicker]="picker">
  <input matStartDate formControlName="start" placeholder="Start date">
  <input matEndDate formControlName="end" placeholder="End date">
</mat-date-range-input>
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
```

TS code:

```
range = new FormGroup({
start: new FormControl(),
end: new FormControl() });
```

[image]

However, When I add another mat-form field underneath with an input everything breaks as below. Why does this happen and how can I prevent it?

```
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
    <mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="range" [rangePicker]="picker">
      <input matStartDate formControlName="start" placeholder="Start date">
      <input matEndDate formControlName="end" placeholder="End date">
    </mat-date-range-input>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
  </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Legacy form field</mat-label>
      <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder">
      <mat-hint>Hint</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have not imported below in module:

```
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';

@NgModule({
     exports: [ MatInputModule, // all other modules
```

If you don't include this, it will break like your scenario shown above.

Documentation: [Input Doc](https://material.angular.io/components/input/api)